# "Optimizing Slow AWS Glue Job with Complex Physical Plan"

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I have an AWS Glue job that processes data from a complex SQL query with a challenging physical execution plan. The job's primary bottleneck appears to be the write operation, which takes approximately 2 hours to complete, but sometimes extends to 4 hours. I'm looking for ways to optimize the code and improve the job's execution speed.

```
 query = '''(
    SELECT * FROM "{schema}"."{source}" i
    INNER JOIN XXX.DAY_CALENDAR ON DAY BETWEEN i.DATE_FROM AND i.DATE_TO
    WHERE DAY BETWEEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate-180, 'yyyyMMdd')) and TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'yyyyMMdd'))
)'''.format(schema=source_schema, source=source_table)


dataframe = glueContext.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver").option("url", url).option("dbtable", query).option("user", user).option("password", psswd).option("fetchsize", 100000).option("batchsize","200000").option("numPartitions", 64).load()

dataframe.show()
print(dataframe)
dataframe = date_column_convertion(dataframe)
dataframe = dataframe.distinct()
dataframe.printSchema()
dataframe.explain()
print(dataframe.explain())
print(dataframe.count())
print(datetime.now())
#dataframe=dataframe.repartition(int(args['repartition']))
#print('repartition completed')

datasource0 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(dataframe, glueContext, "datasource0")
s3_output = args['s3_output']
datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = datasource0, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": s3_output}, format = "parquet", transformation_ctx = "datasink4")
print('Loaded to s3')

== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false 
+- HashAggregate(keys=[...]) 
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(...) 
      +- HashAggregate(keys=[...]) 
         +- Project [cast(...) AS SKU#177L, cast(...) AS LOCATION#229L, cast(...) AS DATE_FROM#872, cast(...) AS DATE_TO#881, cast(...) AS ON_HAND_QTY#385L, cast(...) AS IN_LAYAWAY_QTY#437L, cast(...) AS IN_TRANSIT_QTY#489L, cast(...) AS MPL#541L] 
            +- Scan JDBCRelation((SELECT * FROM "XXX"."ProdTBL" i INNER JOIN XXX.DAY_CALENDAR ON DAY BETWEEN i.DATE_FROM AND i.DATE_TO WHERE DAY BETWEEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate-180, 'yyyyMMdd')) and TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'yyyyMMdd')))) [numPartitions=1] [SKU#0,LOCATION#1,DATE_FROM#2,DATE_TO#3,ON_HAND_QTY#4,IN_LAYAWAY_QTY#5,IN_TRANSIT_QTY#6,MPL#7] PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<SKU:decimal(38,10),LOCATION:decimal(38,10),DATE_FROM:decimal(38,10),DATE_TO:decimal(38,10)...
```

The job involves reading data from a JDBC source with a complex SQL query and then writing the results to S3 in Parquet format.

how to optimize the code for faster execution. Here are a few specific questions:

How can I improve the write to S3, which seems to be the primary bottleneck when I observe in the logs.
Any possible SQL query optimizations I can make?
How overall I can reduce the execution time of this Glue job?